# Retrieving and modifying contents of a marque tag with VB Script

Tags: vbscript, hta

I am a writing a small HTA app which will display, and also modify the contents of a marque element which displays on a company intranet site. I am pretty new to vb script and am unsure how best to do this. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you post What did you write so far ?

Comment: I have written the basic html form, but havent made a start on the vbscript yet. I am not sure whether I should be using a html parser, or if there is an easier way, given that there is only one marque element on the page.

Comment: Ok, what do you expect from Vbscript to do with marquee element ?
Please explain more your needed ! and post your little example

Comment: What I would like to happen, is the hta display the current contents of the marque, and also allow the user to update the marque using the contents a text input and a button on the gui. This marque is currently used to alert viewers of the intranet to system outages and alerts.